# How to see the name of an instance of the class in the class

Tags: javascript, class, instance

I apologize in advance if this question is poorly worded. How could I do something like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  seeName() {
    // ...
  }
}

const foo = new MyClass();
console.log(foo.seeName()); // prints "foo"

const bar = new MyClass();
console.log(bar.seeName()); // prints "bar"
```

Comment: This isn't possible. There's no link back from the object to the variable.

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you do `bar = foo; bar.seeName()`?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? If the instances should have names, make that a property.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
  }

  seeName() {
    return this.name;
  }
}

const foo = new MyClass("foo");
console.log(foo.seeName()); // prints "foo"

const bar = new MyClass("bar");
console.log(bar.seeName()); // prints "bar"
```

Then the name you pass in when you create the object will be stored in the object, but it won't actually know the name of the variable it's stored in.

If you want an better anwser specify what you want to do with the name and what your trying to do in general.